# lsyncd - How to upgrade lsyncd from 2.1.5 to 2.2.3 version

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, backup, synchronization

How to upgrade lsyncd from 2.1.5 to 2.2.3 version using the command prompt. Or how to install lsyncd 2.2.3.

Does have any idea about this upgrade?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.